# UIButton style settings are ignored when I override 'drawRect'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have created a custom iOS numeric keyboard where the buttons have rounded corners:

```
control.layer.cornerRadius = 6;
control.layer.opacity = 1;
```

On one of the buttons I want to draw an image, and I've subclassed the UIButton in order to override the 'drawRect' function.

```
@interface KfKeypadButtonWithDrawing : UIButton

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect;

@end
```

The drawRect implementation just draws some lines on the button. Nothing special.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    [super drawRect:rect];

    // custom drawing code to create an image on the button
}
```

However, as soon as I override `drawRect`, the button ceases to have rounded corners. Is there any way to draw an image on the button AND have the button respect the cornerRadius style setting?

Thanks,

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the things you try to draw in `drawRect` into an image (png, jpg) and use `UIButtons` `setImage:forState` or `setBackgroundImage:forState`.

Comment: We started with an image, but it didn't scale well with changes in the button size. We decided to convert to using drawing code, which is when the rounded corners disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this :

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // the custom drawing
    let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 20)
    UIColor.redColor().setFill()
    roundedRect.fill()

    // call super
    super.drawRect(rect)
}
```